# How to load/alter image metadata in the form of tags?

Tags: r, exiftool

I have a `.csv` file with image file names in column 1, and in column 2 I've got values I would like to assign to images in the form of metadata 'tags' that can be loaded and viewed in programs like digikam.

Does anyone know how they would go about this using R, I know exiftool can be used to load metadata but not sure how to use that to add tags.

Answer (score 0):

With exiftool, the first column of the CSV file would have a header of "SourceFile" with the full name and path to the file.  Any additional columns would have the name of the tag at the top with the data corresponding to each file listed below.  For example

```
SourceFile,XMP-photoshop:Headline,XMP-dc:Description
y:/!temp/Test3.jpg,First Headling,First Description
y:/!temp/Test4.jpg,Second Headling,Second Description
```

Then your command would be
`exiftool -csv=/path/to/file.csv /path/to/files/`

You have to include the path to the files you want to process.  The CSV file is not a listing of files to process, it is a look up table which exiftool uses to check if the file it is currently reading needs to be edited.  Files that are in the CSV file but not in the directory/file list being processed are ignored.  Files that are in the processed directory, but not in the CSV file gives a warning that the file wasn't found in the listing.

Comment: Hi, I think I was a bit unclear in what I meant, I have a .csv file from a different program, the table looks like this: 
| file          | category |
|---------------|----------|
| IMAG0001.JPG  | Human    |
| IMAG0002.JPG  | Animal   |
I would like to make it so that IMAG0001.JPG  now has a 'tag' (something that can be filtered by in a program like digikam) that says 'human'. Do you know of any way to do this?